# IOS - having trouble connecting a segue in a storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am working on my first segue, and I am a bit confused.  I have Made an initial screen with some buttons. Then I made a second screen. Then I clicked on the first screen, went to editor -> embed_in -> NavigationController and that worked.

But the screen I am trying to connect my button to isn't showing up on the storyboard so I am not sure how to connect to it.

I am adding the screenshot of my storyboard.[image]

You see how to storyboard has the Screen with 4 buttons connected to a NavigationController. But how do I get the other controller that I want to be connected to to show up on the same screen and connect to it?

This is the LearningCenter.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LearningCenter : UIViewController

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: so you want to add new viewcontroller to this storyboard and want to connect to the one of the button of the already added as the root controller right?

Comment: @AalokParikh yeah I want the screen with the 4 buttons that is displayed on the left to connect to one of the controllers that I have in my project-navigation panel from the left side of the screen.

Comment: And is there generally a way to make new controllers so they automatically appear on my storyboard? (I only have 1 storyboard so I just need to figure out how to make all the screens/controllers be placed on my storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your object library in Xcode while in the storyboard and search for a view controller and drag it onto the canvas:

[image]

then select the new view controller and go to the identity inspector and replace `UIViewController` with the name of your custom class.

[image]

Now you have "glued" the storyboard view controller with your view controller code in your project.

To answer your second question with the segue: Hold ctrl and click and hold on your button. Then (while still holding ctrl + left mouse!) drag from the button to the new view controllers view. There should now be a segue

Comment: I got a bit confused at the second screen when as example you entered the MyCustomClass. In my case, the controller I want to connect to has two files called LearningCenter.m and LearningCenter.h (not sure which file is what yet lol). Should I enter the name of one of those in that input field there on your second screen?

Comment: if LearningCenter.(h|m) is from type `UIViewController` just type the name in the field and Xcode will autocomplete it. In the end there will just the classname displayed and no .(h|m)

Comment: it actually only autocompleted up to UIView. Does that mean something is off? Once I typed in UIViewController, what do I do next?

Comment: if you type `UIViewController`you say that the view controller in the storyboard is of type `UIViewController`. This is NOT wat you want and need. Type: LearningCenter - Xcode should suggest it after some chars automaticly. If not, then LearningCenter is not a subclass of a `UIViewController` and it won't work.

Comment: ah I unerstand. So I guess LearningCenter is not a subclass of UIViewController. I'll look up how to make it a subclass.  If you know the syntax offhand, would you mind telling me how it should be? I am a bit confused if I should be editing the .h or the .m file.

Comment: When you create your class, `Project->New File->Objective-C class`, when you give a name to your class, select `UIViewController` from the SubClass list.

Comment: you declare the type of a class in the line where `@interface MyViewController : UIViewController` - its in your .h file - since you will need some boilerplate code it may be easier to create a complete new UIViewController file like @luca suggested

Comment: @Pfitz actually the strange thing is that I just looked in the code for the LearningCenter controller and it does subclass the UIViewController

Comment: mh and it doesn't autocomplete? thats strange? normally it should!

Comment: I just updated my original question with the code for the LearningCenter.m file.

Comment: are your shure you selected the view controller in the story board ? (see lower circle) - it can be that you accidentally selected some other object. What happens if you type LearningCenter in the class text field ? does it work? maybe a xcode reboot ?

Comment: I played with it and I got it to work for the most part. Still playing with it.  Thank you very much :)